# Python can not find enviroment key although it's there

Tags: python

I have saved my API KEY as an enviroment variable through `Advanced system settings` menu. 
I am trying to get the value of that api key using python code:

```
print(os.environ.get("MY_API_KEY"))
```

but I only get 
`none` for my output. WHat might be the problem?

Comment: Not sure what `Advanced system settings` is. Have you tried sourcing the `env` file or reloading the window (if you're using an application to set your env vars)? Also, have you made sure you're not running on a virtual environment?

Comment: So is this on a windows? or mac etc - in either case you should try to set  it using  the command line. (For example with my mac)

```export MY_API_KEY=blah```

then check with 

```echo $MY_API_KEY```

Comment: Please try to close you python develop tools.  and then restart run.

Comment: After setting the variable, did you **logout** (if it's a ***User var***) or **reboot** (if it's a ***System var***)?